# how to sort a column of a table in database with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to find 10 nearset value of a column of a table in a database to my value.
so I want to sort the value of that column, and then find 10 smaller or bigger value than my value.
how can I do this
thanks a lot  for your help

Comment: Try this: `getSession().createQuery("FROM TableName t WHERE t.SomeField < " 
          + fieldvalue + " ORDER BY SomeField asc").setMaxResults(10).list();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL supports `ORDER BY`.

Either you do

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Table order by abs(value - :v) asc";
q.setXxx("v", myValue);         /* Xxx is Float or Long or Integer or... */
q.setMaxResults(10);
List<Table> l = q.list();
```

or

```
Query q1 = session.createQuery("from Table where value >= :v order by value asc";
q1.setXxx("v", myValue);         /* Xxx is Float or Long or Integer or... */
q1.setMaxResults(10);
List<Table> l1 = q1.list();
Query q2 = session.createQuery("from Table where value < :v order by value desc";
q2.setXxx("v", myValue);         /* Xxx is Float or Long or Integer or... */
q2.setMaxResults(10);
List<Table> l2 = q2.list();
/* now find the 10 nearest elements in Java code */
...
while (...) {
   ...
}
```

In the second example you have the inconvenience of two selects which give you 20 rows altogether and then you have to find the 10 nearest in Java code, but if there is a database index on the value column it might b a lot faster. The result will be the same for both examples.